# telegram bots: how to create an instant view button?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I know I can place a link like http://telegra.ph/some-page-slug inside a Telegram message, and it will be rendered with an Instant View feature. But if i embed the link inside an inline button I run into two issues:

- the button shows a confirmation screen, and I cannot avoid it
- telegra.ph pages are opened as regular websites without any instant view.

[image]

is there a way to avoid any of these two problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. For security reasons, any link will show confirm pop-up, except non-format text link.
2. You need to put link in message text, and link will show webpage preview with Instant View button